# How to make content editable from admin page?

Tags: theme-development, admin, actions, editor

I have a landing page that has to be somehow converted into wordpress theme. And what I want to do is to make an admin page with editable fields that will correspond to the content on the front end.

For example: in the admin page the title would say "Testimonials" which is going to refer to the same section on the front end. And for each testimonial I could edit the testimonial's text and autor's name. Can you point me to the specific part of the codex or present the example code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to pay attention to two concepts:

- Use a [static page as home page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), this will allow you to create a page in the backend and assign it to the front page location. You will also be able to assign a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) to it.
- Your testimonials will likely need to be a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types), using the `the_title()` as the author name and `the_content()` as author description. Which you can then iterate through, and display, on a page template.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood you correctly, I need to create a custom post type for every section of my page, then to render all those sections I use loop through the posts?

Comment: From your question, it looks like you would only need to create a custom post type for testimonials and then where you want them to display you would loop through them using `new WP_Query( 'post_type' => 'testimonials-cpt' )`.

Comment: Yes, but I need the whole page to be editable, not only testimonials. Other section's text and images I should be able to edit. And I'm not a specialist in any PHP and WP, just do everything from tutorials. The thing is that there no tutorial on my problem.

Comment: It looks like your missing the fundamentals. You approaching this too holistically. In general, WordPress's home pages are generally maid up of many smaller components/partials of different loops and functionality.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but still haven't got any answer. Can I implement requested functionality through theme options? I know there is a way to set options from the admin page and then display them on the front end.

Comment: This answer by @Lawless is definitely the way to go if you are comfortable with writing basic code. By creating a custom post type (`testimonial` for example) you will get a ton of functionality right out of the box including the admin UI which you can use to populate testimonial content. You can use the title field for the testimonial provider's name and the content area for the message. In your homepage template, get results for the `testimonial` post type using `WP_Query` and output results with a custom loop. (BTW, theme options is a separate concept entirely, and not the way to go here.)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few testimonial plugins available for that specific requirement.  However, if you need a more customised form for your users to fill in content and for each submissions to be saved as custom posts in the backend, I use contact form 7 along with 2 other extentions for such kind of problems,

- [Smart Grid-layout Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) that allows you to create rich form layouts using a grid UI.
- [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) which allow you to map a cf7 form to a post and therefore save all your submissions as posts in your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, but users won't be able to edit anything. The only editor will be the admin.  I need the whole page to be editable from the admin page.